# How do I set an animated desktop background without OnyX?

Tags: macos, desktop, wallpaper

In OnyX, there is a setting in **Parameters > General > Animated desktop background:** where animated wallpapers can be set. While this doesn't seem to work very seamlessly (moving between spaces displays old wallpaper briefly etc.) and doesn't persist over restarts, I wonder how OnyX does this.

Is there some hidden setting where one can do this without OnyX?

Note that my question is not about how to set gifs as wallpapers (although maybe this is what OnyX does?).

System: 10.11.5

Comment: Before you change my edits [please look at this image](http://i.imgur.com/apTELbS.png), specifically the red arrows in the image as it shows that the application's name is in fact spelt with a capital X on the end, not a lower case x, "OnyX" and the path in the application for the topic of discussion is **Parameters > General > Animated desktop background:* not "Parameters > Animated Desktop Background", as there are 8 different tabs for the Parameters it is standard practice to include, in this instance, "General" as part of the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done without OnyX.

> First head to **System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen
>   Saver** and select one of the screen savers included in OS X, or a
>   third party screen saver that you’ve previously installed. Whichever
>   one you choose, just make sure it’s selected as the active screen
>   saver, even if you have it set to never start in the “Start After”
>   duration drop-down menu.
>
> Next, launch Terminal (located in the **Applications > Utilities**
>   folder), copy and paste the following command, and press the Return
>   key on your keyboard to execute it:
>
> ```
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background
> ```

Source: [How to Set a Screen Saver as the Desktop Background in Mac OS X](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/screen-saver-desktop-background-mac-os-x/)